How can I measure the time a user spends on my dashboard?
I have implemented a transaction (with startTransaction) to track the time a user spends on my dashboard, but startTransaction is deprecated in the next version of sentry.
I wanted to migrate to this new version at some point.
But now, Sentry suggests to replace it by startStan() but this function only measures the time it takes for a function to execute.
Is there an other solution for my need?

startSpan() and startTransaction() are semantically more or less equivalent. startSpan() is the new API as it is more aligned with the Opentelemetry API which the SDK is gonna use under the hood in the future.
One of startSpan(), startInactiveSpan() or startSpanManual(), should fit your need perfectly.

For example: export const App = () => {
const transaction = useMemo(() => { return Sentry.startTransation() }, []);
return <button onClick={() => transaction.finish()} />}
I am unable to measure the same thing with startSpan() which need a callback.

I updated my answer, in this case you likely want to use startSpanManual instead.
